# VirtualBox prevent user to leave VM

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, hotkeys

hopefully my question is ok here :)

I have to modify a Virtualbox VM (Debian OS) so that a user cannot leave this VM. Therefore, the VM has to capture all user interactions until the VM is shutdown.

I know, the easiest solution would be a second OS running on this computer but I cannot do that.

I've googled and there were some Threads telling me to "run commands" but I do not even have the slightest hint where to execute them.

Any help is appreciated :)

Greetz, Paddaels

Comment: This won't be possible with VirtualBox which has several methods to escape the VM.  Now you could boot directly to the VM in theory but that is a greater technical challenge

Comment: And I cannot do that :/

Comment: If you don't install the guest addons and you change the host-key to something people can't guess, it will be very hard to get out of the VM once the session was activated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but we will do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Since Virtualbox has a lot of mechanisms to leave the vm, we will do it as followed.

- The vm will run in fullscreen
- The supervisor will have a look on each screen
- We will configure our os so nobody can use firefox to google for results.

Thanks a lot for your help :)